# show hide nested ul(s) with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have li list with which exapands fine if i click the li are but i want it to expand if i click the link 'a' not the li.

how do i make the jquery below work on the a not the li?

below is the code i have so far:

```
$("#leftcontent ul li:not(:has(li.current))").find("ul").hide().end() // Hide all other ULs
    .click(function(e) {
        if (this == e.target) {  // if the handler element is where the event originated
            $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
        }
});
```

Comment: Share your markup... it's beautiful when you ask with a full pack of code. Throw it at us, we love swimming in it.

Comment: Some HTML would be nice, a JSFiddle would be even better...

Comment: yup, we need to see some html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#leftcontent li > a").click(function() {
    // get the parent <li> of the <a>
    var li = $(this).closest('li');
    // open the child <ul> of the <li>
    li.find(' > ul').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ye6U5/

And to hide nested uls onload:

```
$(function() {
    $("#leftcontent li > ul").hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ye6U5/1/

Comment: this worked perfectly... now is there a way i can hide the leftcontent nested uls on load?